# Extracting React Array of Elements Into a Function Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-forwardref

I'm trying to use this component that I wrote:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

const ITEMS = {
  item1: { id: 1, name: '1', description: 'item1', protected: true },
  item2: { id: 2, name: '2', description: 'item2' },
  item3: { id: 3, name: '3', description: 'item3' },
}

// See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20356#issuecomment-435708501
// for an explanation on why the component return type was cast to `any` below.
const MenuItemList: any = () => {
  return Object.values(ITEMS).map(
    (item) =>
      !item.protected && (
        <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
          <ListItemText
            primary={item.name}
            secondary={item.description}
          />
        </MenuItem>
      )
  );
};

export default MenuItemList;
```

...once inside a `Textfield` of type `select` and another time inside a `Menu` component. However, I'm getting the following error when it's accessed in the browser:

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

**UPDATE:**

Here is how I'm calling this component:

```js
<Menu
  id={id}
  open={open}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  getContentAnchorEl={null}
  keepMounted={false}
  onClose={handleClose}
  elevation={2}
  PaperProps={{
      square: true,
  }}
  anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: 'bottom',
      horizontal: 'right',
  }}
  transformOrigin={{
      vertical: 'top',
      horizontal: 'right',
  }}
>
  < MenuItemList />
</Menu>
```

```js
<Field
  name="items"
  label="Select Item"
  padding={2}
  component={TextField}
  select
  fullWidth
  SelectProps={{
    MenuProps: {
      elevation: 2,
      getContentAnchorEl: null,
      anchorOrigin: {
        vertical: 'bottom',
        horizontal: 'left',
      },
      transformOrigin: {
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'left',
      },
    },
    IconComponent: ExpandMoreIcon,
  }}
  variant="filled"
  InputProps={{
    disableUnderline: true,
  }}
>
  <MenuItemList />
</Field>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's the error stack:

```
Check the render method of `ForwardRef(Menu)`.
    in MenuItemList (at ShowItemsDialog.tsx:105)
    in ul (created by ForwardRef(List))
    in ForwardRef(List) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)) (created by ForwardRef(MenuList))
    in ForwardRef(MenuList) (created by ForwardRef(Menu))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Transition)
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Grow))
    in ForwardRef(Grow) (created by TrapFocus)
    in TrapFocus (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Portal) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Modal) (created by ForwardRef(Popover))
    in ForwardRef(Popover) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Popover)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Popover)) (created by ForwardRef(Menu))
    in ForwardRef(Menu) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Menu)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Menu)) (created by ForwardRef(SelectInput))
    in ForwardRef(SelectInput) (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in ForwardRef(InputBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)) (created by ForwardRef(FilledInput))
    in ForwardRef(FilledInput) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(FilledInput)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(FilledInput)) (created by ForwardRef(Select))
    in ForwardRef(Select) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Select)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Select)) (created by ForwardRef(TextField))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(FormControl))
    in ForwardRef(FormControl) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(FormControl)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(FormControl)) (created by ForwardRef(TextField))
    in ForwardRef(TextField) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField)) (created by FormikMaterialUITextField)
    in FormikMaterialUITextField (created by Field)
    in Field (at ShowItemsDialog.tsx:77)
```

Comment: Please create a working example (you can use https://codesandbox.io for that).

Comment: The code you showed us doesn't make any use of refs. When you render a `<MenuItemList />`, are you trying to pass in a ref?

Comment: Not at all, I'm only rendering the component as is. Might it be the `TextField` that automatically does that?

Comment: @NicholasTower I think the error stack above shows who's trying to pass in the ref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stefano.orlando's explanation appears to be correct, up until the solution they propose. Wrapping a div around the other components does not cause refs to be forwarded. For that you need to use React.forwardRef. The following code will make it so that if a ref is passed into `MenuItemList`, that ref will be redirected to the first `MenuItem` inside `MenuItemList` instead:

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

const ITEMS = {
  item1: { id: 1, name: '1', description: 'item1', protected: true },
  item2: { id: 2, name: '2', description: 'item2' },
  item3: { id: 3, name: '3', description: 'item3' },
}

const MenuItemList: any = React.ForwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    Object.values(ITEMS)
      .filter(item => !item.protected)
      .map((item, index) => (
        <MenuItem 
          ref={index === 0 ? ref : undefined}
          key={item.id} 
          value={item.id}
        >
          <ListItemText primary={item.name} secondary={item.description} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))
  );
});

export default MenuItemList;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this right away! Any idea how to type `props` and `ref` above?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is not on this component. Could you paste the code of the component where you use `MenuItemList`? Seems to be a problem on the [ref react](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) used by Material-ui

I also recommend using `filter` [[doc]](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the protected items.

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

const ITEMS = {
  item1: { id: 1, name: '1', description: 'item1', protected: true },
  item2: { id: 2, name: '2', description: 'item2' },
  item3: { id: 3, name: '3', description: 'item3' },
}

const MenuItemList: any = () => {
  return Object.values(ITEMS).filter(item => !item.protected).map(
    (item) =>
        <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
          <ListItemText
            primary={item.name}
            secondary={item.description}
          />
        </MenuItem>
  );
};

export default MenuItemList;
```

**Edit**

Menu uses the first child of the Menu as the "content anchor" for the Popover component used internally by Menu. The "content anchor" is the DOM element within the menu that Popover attempts to line up with the anchor element (the element outside of the menu that is the reference point for positioning the menu).

In order to leverage the first child as the content anchor, Menu adds a ref to it (using cloneElement). In order to not get the error you received (and for the positioning to work correctly), your function component needs to forward the ref to one of the components it renders (generally the outermost component — a div in your case).

When you use a div as the direct child of Menu, you don’t get the error because the div can receive a ref successfully.

So you should change the code of `MenuItemList` to:

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

const ITEMS = {
  item1: { id: 1, name: '1', description: 'item1', protected: true },
  item2: { id: 2, name: '2', description: 'item2' },
  item3: { id: 3, name: '3', description: 'item3' },
}

const MenuItemList: any = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.values(ITEMS)
        .filter(item => !item.protected)
        .map(item => (
          <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
            <ListItemText primary={item.name} secondary={item.description} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuItemList;
```

Comment: I just updated the question to show how I'm calling it exactly.

Comment: I modified the original answer, let me know if it's clearer! @Sammy

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefano, but even with the `div` in place I get the exact same error and error stack above :-(